# View of a Fragment becoming null at the time of onSaveInstanceState() callback

Tags: android

I have a `Fragment`(used support library) like this

```
public class ItemDetailsFragment extends Fragment {
    private ListView itemsListView;

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        itemsListView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listMode);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        ItemsAdapter adapter = (ItemsAdapter) itemsListView.getAdapter();
        ArrayList<String> items = adapter.getItems();
        outState.putStringArrayList("some_key", items);
    }
}
```

Note that `itemsListView` is initialized properly. and when I set Adapter to this ListView, ListView is showing items properly. but when I call

```
 itemsListView.getAdapter();
```

in `onSaveInstanceState` callback, I am getting NPE and I recognized that `itemsListView` is `null` while debugging. I am confident that I am not assigning `itemsListView` to `null` through out the `Fragment`. More over, I am getting this NPE error only sometimes but I am unable to say when it is.

Where the error might be? why `itemsListView` is becoming `null` only some times?

Thanks to all...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a note in Android documentation on [`onSaveInstanceState` fragments](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onSaveInstanceState%28android.os.Bundle%29):

> This corresponds to Activity.onSaveInstanceState(Bundle) and most of the discussion there applies here as well. Note however: this method may be called at any time before onDestroy(). There are many situations where a fragment may be mostly torn down (such as when placed on the back stack with no UI showing), but its state will not be saved until its owning activity actually needs to save its state.

It makes using `onSaveInstanceState` methods for fragments rather tricky.

Comment: but why I am getting that NPE error only very less times?

Comment: I don't think it's all happening in a predictable fashion. Many things in Android are not synchronous so you sometimes can't tell when exactly things are going to happen.

Comment: @RuntimeException To get around it, I personally do not relied on the view being there at the time of onSaveInstanceState and stored needed values in variables on fragment.

Comment: @Szymon What happens when the fragment gets destroyed but onSaveInstanceState gets called after? What happens to those stored variables in the fragment?